# App only displays default view when added to page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a very large list with multiple views on it. However, when I add the app to a site page, it only displays one view. When you click on the title of the list, it takes you in the background as if you accessed it through site contents. Here you can quickly skip around between all the views. Why isn't the app the same when you add it to a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the view selector for the list view web part:

1. Edit Web Part
2. Expand Miscellaneous
3. Uncheck **Disable View Selector Menu**
4. Click **Apply**
5. Save page

Note that changing views this way directs to the view page; the user will not remain on the page.

Comment: Warmer. Another problem is that I have a script editor on the page which gives the app sticky headers on the columns. This animation is lost once you leave the page.

Comment: Can you add the script to the views as well? Or perhaps create several pages, put the different views on them along with the script, and add a custom view selector to them.

Comment: I'm following the create several pages idea. I'm not sure what a custom view selector is though.

Comment: It's exactly what it sounds like.  Just something that you create that will allow users to navigate to the different pages.  Whether it's as simple as links, or a drop down menu.

Comment: I just put the different views on separate pages and edited the web part so it doesn't show the option to switch views. I then added links above the lists to the other views. Looks great!

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the view on a list that you have added as an app part to a page you would:

1. Edit the page
2. Hover over the upper right hand corner of your app part, click the down arrow that appears and choose "Edit Web Part"
3. A dialog box will appear to the right of all your page content. In this dialog box there is a drop down box under the *Selected View* heading where you can choose the view you want to be shown on the page.

Comment: For an everyday user who isn't a site owner, they can't do this. That's the problem.